# how to convert array api response to json in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have an api which return data structured like this :

//code
 return response.status(200).json(startdate)

results data:

```
[
    "2020-01-16",
    "2020-01-18",
]
```

i want that this api to return result like this:

```
Code: 200
Content:
{
    "availableDates": [
      "2017-11-24",
      "2017-11-27"
    ],
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "message": ""
}
```

this is my full code where i get the data as array

```
app.get('/api/getBusyDays',(request, response) =>{
    odoo.connect(function (err) {



        console.log(' OdooStartDate' + dateTimeStartUsed + 'OdooStopdate' + dateTimeEndUsed);
        var params1 = [];
        params1.push(inParams1);

        console.log(' search params '+ JSON.stringify(params1));
        odoo.execute_kw('calendar.event', 'search_read', params1, function (err, value) {
            if (err) { return console.log(err) }
            if(value) {
                if (value.length > 0) {


                    value.forEach(function(a) {
                        a.start_datetime = moment(a.start_datetime).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        a.stop_datetime = moment(a.stop_datetime).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    });

                    const startdate = [...new Set(value.map(val => val.start_datetime))];

                    startdate.sort();


                   // return response.status(200).json( value)

                    return response.status(200).json(startdate)
                }
            }
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: don't know how to convert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just create an object like this:

```js
let arrVal = [
  "2017-11-24",
  "2017-11-27"
];
// return Object or your framework (Express or KOA or) response Object
console.log({
  "Code": 200,
  "Content": {
    "availableDates": arrVal,
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "message": ""
  }
})
```

**Update**:

Based on the comments on this answer, modify your response so it looks like this:

```
app.get('/api/getBusyDays',(request, response) =>{
    odoo.connect(function (err) {



        console.log(' OdooStartDate' + dateTimeStartUsed + 'OdooStopdate' + dateTimeEndUsed);
        var params1 = [];
        params1.push(inParams1);

        console.log(' search params '+ JSON.stringify(params1));
        odoo.execute_kw('calendar.event', 'search_read', params1, function (err, value) {
            if (err) { return console.log(err) }
            if(value) {
                if (value.length > 0) {


                    value.forEach(function(a) {
                        a.start_datetime = moment(a.start_datetime).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                        a.stop_datetime = moment(a.stop_datetime).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
                    });

                    const startdate = [...new Set(value.map(val => val.start_datetime))];

                    startdate.sort();


                   // return response.status(200).json( value)

                    return response.status(200).json({"code": 200, "content": {"availableDates": startdate, "status": "SUCCESS", "message": ""}})
                }
            }
```

Comment: sorry i reformulated my question maybe it was not clear the idea

Comment: @Alia do you have access to the API code base? and which framework are you using?

Comment: i cant add all the code ...but the idea is that api works well , just i want to have result not like array but json with status inside and message

Comment: if you want the response to be like this, then you have to modify the response to be an object and change the frontend implementation, `response.status(200)` only modify the response header status code and it doesn't create an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an empty object and set properties to it and send it as response from ur node api service.

```
let data = [
    "2017-11-24",
    "2017-11-27"
];

let response = [];
response.data = data;
response.code = 200;
response.status = 'success';
response.message = 'Mission Successful';

return response;
```